# Could not add the object to the LDAP server

Tags: php, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I'm using an LDAP server and I'm trying to create an object at Organsation level.

But when I try to create an object filling all properties, it throws me the below error.

```
Could not add the object to the LDAP server.
LDAP said:  Object class violation
Error number:   0x41 (LDAP_OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION)
Description:    You tried to perform an operation that would cause an undefined attribute   
                to exist or that would remove a required attribute, given the current list   
                of ObjectClasses. This can also occur if you do not specify a structural   
                objectClass when creating an entry, or if you specify more than one structural objectClass.
```

Is there any way to get more information about this error from some log file ?

Have anyone faced this error before ? If yes, please share a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to add an object which is missing a required attribute from one of the defined in objectClass. Check all required attributes from object classes that you are using.

```
Error:  LDAP_OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION
Number: 65 (0x41)
Cause:  An object class violation occurred when using the current schema, for example, a "must" attribute was missing when adding an entry.
```